# SLO. Error MSIS7074 on ADFS

Tags: spring-security, saml, adfs

I work with ADFS 2.0 by SAML using spring-security-saml2-core (1.0.0.RC2). I use HTTP-POST binding. But I have a problem with SingleLogout.

Application receive LogoutRequest

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest
     xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
     Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" 
     Destination="https://myhost:8443/my/saml/SingleLogout/alias/defaultAlias" 
     ID="_438dcef8-cd64-4e04-8e11-e87705f26b6c" 
     IssueInstant="2014-08-01T10:53:14.641Z" 
     NotOnOrAfter="2014-08-01T10:58:14.641Z" 
     Version="2.0">
     <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://adfs-server.local/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
     <NameID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">nata</NameID>
     <samlp:SessionIndex>_34e48828-a6b5-47c2-96fd-595f9d0a88b7</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

And send LogoutResponse

```
<saml2p:LogoutResponse 
     xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
     Destination="https://adfs-server.local/adfs/ls/" 
     ID="a2ddb014h7d7558f3cd5hfge981bicf" 
     InResponseTo="_438dcef8-cd64-4e04-8e11-e87705f26b6c" 
     IssueInstant="2014-08-01T10:53:43.808Z" 
     Version="2.0">
     <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://myhost:8443/my/saml/metadata/alias/defaultAlias</saml2:Issuer>
     <saml2p:Status>
             <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
     </saml2p:Status>
 </saml2p:LogoutResponse>
```

But ADFS throw error of closing SAML-endpoint:

MSIS7074: SAML authentication request for the WebSSO profile must specify an issuer with no NameQualifier, SPNameQualifier or SPProvidedId properties.

My configuration for SingleLogout:

```
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
<bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <array value-type="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler">
            <ref bean="logoutHandler"/>
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
</bean>
<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<bean id="logoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paullem is right. Our Windows Server is 2012 R2, ADFS 3.0.

SAML LogoutRequest messages must be signed. Error was fixed. We set parameter requireLogoutResponseSigned in ''true" in ExtendedMetadata.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
    <property name="local" value="false" />
    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false" />
    <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="true"/> 
</bean>
```

Comment: You did this on the SDP or on the IP? I have the same error but cannot find a solution

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. We used SAML protocol. This is part of our spring-context for the work with ADFS.

Comment: Maybe Cito was asking if this snippet is inside `org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter` (SDP side) or in the IDP Metadata configuration.

Answer (score 1):

:-) ouch this was confusing..... And cross-posting??

First of all: My ADFS servers 2.x, on S2008(R2) and S2012 do not have that message. So I believe it cannot be ADFS 2.0. I assume that you are working on the ADFS server on Windows Server 2012R2 (which is never identified as 2.0).   :-(

The message (about AuthnRequest vs. LogoutResponse) does seem totally out of place. It looks like you ran in to a minor (super confusing) bug of ADFS on S2012R2. Because ADFS 2.0 would have said something else in that case. It would have said [in the ValidateSignatureRequirements(SamlMessage) method]:
 "MSIS1014: SAML LogoutRequest and LogoutResponse messages must be signed when using SAML HTTP Redirect or HTTP POST binding."

So you have a bug to file at Microsoft (a reference to this description could help you). Meanwhile you should ask the SP to sign the LogoutResponse. I am somewhat surprised that ADFS did not sign the LogoutRequest. It normally does sign the LogoutRequest.