# ADFS NullReference exception on SAML logout (event 303)

Tags: events, nullreferenceexception, adfs, spring-saml

I use Spring-Security-Saml sample app as a SP and ADFS 2.0 as an IdP. I followed instructions described here http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/ . After setting it up I can login into the system, but on global logout  ADFS throws NullReferenceException (Event Id 303):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SingleLogoutService.LogoutNextSessionParticipant()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SingleLogoutService.ProcessLogoutRequest(LogoutRequest logoutRequest, Boolean& validLogoutRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SingleLogoutService.ProcessMessage(SamlMessage samlMessage, BindingInformation bindingInformation, Boolean validResponseMessage, Boolean& validLogoutRequest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same problem, except in my case, I was using ADFS 3.0. Telling Spring Security SAML to sign the logout response fixed it for me. This is configured by setting `requireLogoutResponseSigned` on the [ExtendedMetadata bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/saml/metadata/ExtendedMetadata.html#setRequireLogoutResponseSigned(boolean)) to `true`.

---

The null reference error message isn't very helpful. When I enabled tracing in the `C:\Windows\ADFS\Microsoft.DeviceRegistration.ServiceHost.exe.config` file, I got the following error message in the tracing log in Event Viewer.

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSignatureVerificationException: MSIS7074: SAML authentication request for the WebSSO profile must specify an issuer with no NameQualifier, SPNameQualifier or SPProvidedId properties.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.ValidateSignatureRequirements(SamlMessage samlMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Logout(HttpSamlMessage logoutMessage, String sessionState, String logoutState, Boolean partialLogout, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, HttpSamlMessage& newLogoutMessage, String& newSessionState, String& newLogoutState)
```

Searching for that gives some more helpful results.

[SLO. Error MSIS7074 on ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131206/slo-error-msis7074-on-adfs)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85b1a66f-ca0b-4ed6-a32f-c8dca4fdd6c7/slo-error-msis7074-on-adfs?forum=Geneva